# How to check a Condition in .cshtml file

Tags: c#, razor, model-view-controller

I want to check the `FormattedLastFillDate` field ...Some how syntax is throwing an error...Can any one help to write a If condition in **`.cshtml`** file...Below is the block of code.

```
 @if ( FormattedLastFillDate!= "My logic")                        
    <tr>
        <td class="td--numeric">{{OrderNumber}}</td>
        <td>
            <a href="@Url.Action(Mvc.Public.JavaScriptRequired())" onclick="popDrugImprint('{{Ndc}}', '{{{& DrugName}}}'); return false;">{{DrugName}}</a>
            <div class="order-directions">{{Directions}}</div>
            <div class="order-message">{{Message}}</div>
        </td>
        <td>{{DrugStrength}}</td>
        <td>{{DrugForm}}</td>
        <td class="td--numeric">{{FormattedRefillsLeft}}</td>
        <td class="td--numeric">{{Ndc}}</td>
        <td class="td--numeric">{{FormattedLastFillDate}}</td>
     </tr>
```

Comment: Probably need to add `{` and `}` around the block after the `if`.

Comment: BTW: **WHICH ERROR?**

Comment: Put error so can understand and solve it

Answer (score 0):

you need to try this one:

```
@if ( FormattedLastFillDate!= "My logic")
{                    
<tr>
    <td class="td--numeric">{{OrderNumber}}</td>
    <td>
        <a href="@Url.Action(Mvc.Public.JavaScriptRequired())" onclick="popDrugImprint('{{Ndc}}', '{{{& DrugName}}}'); return false;">{{DrugName}}</a>
        <div class="order-directions">{{Directions}}</div>
        <div class="order-message">{{Message}}</div>
    </td>
    <td>{{DrugStrength}}</td>
    <td>{{DrugForm}}</td>
    <td class="td--numeric">{{FormattedRefillsLeft}}</td>
    <td class="td--numeric">{{Ndc}}</td>
    <td class="td--numeric">{{FormattedLastFillDate}}</td>
 </tr>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the variable should be accessible mode.
I think you were pretty close, try this:

```
*@{string FormattedLastFillDate= "test";}
@if (FormattedLastFillDate != "test")
{ <tr>
        <td class="td--numeric">{{OrderNumber}}</td>
        <td>
            <a href="@Url.Action(Mvc.Public.JavaScriptRequired())" onclick="popDrugImprint('{{Ndc}}', '{{{& DrugName}}}'); return false;">{{DrugName}}</a>
            <div class="order-directions">{{Directions}}</div>
            <div class="order-message">{{Message}}</div>
        </td>
        <td>{{DrugStrength}}</td>
        <td>{{DrugForm}}</td>
        <td class="td--numeric">{{FormattedRefillsLeft}}</td>
        <td class="td--numeric">{{Ndc}}</td>
        <td class="td--numeric">{{FormattedLastFillDate}}</td>
     </tr>
}*
```